# How to combine parsing arguments in BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my 1st attempt at scraping right out of the book.
I managed to achieve what i needed however I think I can skip 1 step, if I knew how.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/")
print(page.status_code)

soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')


res = soup.find('ul', class_='Carousel-Slider Pos(r) Whs(nw)')

ticker = res.find_all('li')
```

I think I could combine the last 2 lines, if I knew how....

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If combine means chain, you can do it this way:

```
ticker = soup.find('ul', class_='Carousel-Slider Pos(r) Whs(nw)').find_all('li')
```

or with `css selectors` -  It would also be a better strategy to use the tag or attribute `id` instead of `class` cause first two are more static than the last one:

```
ticker = soup.select('ul.Carousel-Slider li[id*="marketsummary-itm"]')
```

Comment: the chain worked; however the css.selector gave me an error; somehow the '(' were not welcome. How do you highlight text here?

Comment: That is correct not sure if they could be escaped but they are not neccessary. It would be a better strategy to use the tag or attribute `id` instead of `class` cause first two are more static than the last one.  To highlight code set it in backticks.

Comment: Thanks `Hedgehog`. See the backticks works.